# composer + rocketeer + laravel 5.1 - cannot install rocketeer in laravel 5.1.17

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, rocketeer

I tried to install rocketeer on laravel 5.1.17 using composer but couldn't succeed.
[image]

Is it incompatible with latest version of laravel or what might be the problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you show your composer.json file?

Answer (score 0):

The latest versions of the illuminate/log are 4.2.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, and 5.2.x-dev.

This means that you want to add this line to the end of yourcomposer.json file:

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```